# Tabs with one similar field

Tags: forms, tabs

I am creating an webpage that will allow our support team to create licenses for different use cases. For example, we sometimes need to generate a temporary "Emergency" license for the client if something went wrong with their system.

The idea is to simplify the interface so that generating these emergency licenses is easy enough for anyone on our support team can generate them. We also have another use case but I'll leave that out for now.

Anyways, the different use cases for the license generation require different information (We can default a lot for the emergency licenses). But one field is the same for all of them.

My idea was to just have this field occur on all of the tabs in the same spot, we could even have the typed in data for this field persist when you switch tabs. However, somebody else recommended pulling this field above the tabs so it is always visible. Is there a standard for this? How do I assess this in terms of a better UI/UX?

Edit: There are now 2 of the same fields.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Without a screenshot or a mockup we can't imagine what _"...a field occur on all of the tabs in the same spot..."_ means. Do you have to implement those use cases using exactly same UI? Amazon, for example, has a very different workflow for "normal" orders and "1-click" orders...

Comment: I added some sketches and now there are 2 of the same fields that will be on all tabs, those are the top two: Version and Host ID

Comment: I'm guessing "Generate" is also repeated.

Comment: Yes, this is correct

Comment: Basically, my question is: Should I leave all of the fields under the tabs even though some of them are the same between tabs, or is there any reason to bring those out of the tabs to show that they are persistent across the tabs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do separate, here's one way to do that:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEqWbl.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

However, IMHO, the difference between the two is marginal, so, depending on your user base, how many users, how savvy they are, you may choose the simpler interface to implement.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even think about having the middle section be enclosed like that and having the generate button outside of that.